# How do ingress host name work on internet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I using NodePort service (with kubeadm) to create ingress, the result show below.

```
NAME          HOSTS                ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
app-ingress   example.com          10.110.161.218   80      12m
```

Any detail in ingress.

```
Name:             app-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          10.110.161.218
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  example.com
                      /my-api   user-api:3000 (172.10.118.201:3000)
```

How to let the host name `example.com` accessible on internet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [external dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) project to configure external DNS servers (AWS Route53, Google CloudDNS and others) for Kubernetes Ingresses and Services.

Comment: Could I use my own domain name relate to this host name?

Comment: yes you can ...check this example of using nginx on GKE but it should work on any provider which external dns project supports https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/nginx-ingress.md